# tobit two-stage in R

Tags: r, tobit-regression, two-step-estimation

I'm working with a dependent variable $y_i \in [0,1]$. I have a single *endogenous* explanatory variable $w_i \in [0, 1]$ with corresponding instrument $z_i \in \{0,1\}$. Suppose further that I have a vector of *exogenous* explanatory control variables $\vec{x_i}$.

My intuition is to estimate a two-stage tobit model. Is this possible? Are there any caveats to doing this? Can I do this in R?

Comment: Does the zero correspond to censoring or a corner solution?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that the zero corresponds to a corner solution in both cases.

Comment: Correction: the [0,100] closed interval corresponds to two corner solutions.

Comment: You might find my answer to this question useful.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66856/instrumental-variable-tobit-in-r/69588#69588