# 2SLS or IV with a tobit distribution in the first stage

Tags: r, instrumental-variables, tobit-regression, two-step-estimation

I would like to use a two stage least squares approach (2SLS), where the first stage would benefit from a Tobit specification.

I cross posted this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291953/2sls-or-iv-with-a-tobit-distribution-in-the-first-stage) because there might be quite some coding involved.
I have some sample data as follows:

```
panelID= c(1:50)
year= c(2005, 2010)
country = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
urban = c("A", "B", "C")
indust = c("D", "E", "F")
sizes = c(1,2,3,4,5)
n <- 2
library(AER)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(   country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                    sales= round(rnorm(10,10,10),2),
                    industry = rep(sample(indust, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    urbanisation = rep(sample(urban, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    size = rep(sample(sizes, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n))
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(base_rate = as.integer(runif(1, 12.5, 37.5))) %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(taxrate = base_rate + as.integer(runif(1,-2.5,+2.5)))
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(vote = sample(c(0,1),1), 
votewon = ifelse(vote==1, sample(c(0,1),1),0))
```

Say I would like to run:

```
summary(ivreg(sales ~ taxrate + as.factor(industry) + as.factor(size) + as.factor(urbanisation) + as.factor(vote) | as.factor(votewon) + as.factor(industry) + as.factor(size) + as.factor(urbanisation) + as.factor(vote), data=DT))
```

But I want the first stage to be a tobit specification? Something like:

```
tobit_reg <<- censReg(taxrate ~ as.factor(votewon) + as.factor(industry) + as.factor(size) + as.factor(urbanisation) + as.factor(vote), left=3, right=15, data=DT)
summary(tobit_reg)
```

How can I have the tobit regression as the first stage for the 2SLS?

I would additionally like to test for over identification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perform a 2SLS approach by hand, where you estimate a Tobit model of the instrument in the first stage and use the fitted values $\hat y_2$ to estimate an OLS model in the second stage.

The naïve standard errors won't be valid though, because they do not consider that the $\hat y_2$ itself is an estimate; only the variance of the residuals of the second stage are used to calculate the standard errors.

Therefore we have to correct the variance-covariance matrix (VCOV) by applying the correct RMSE using the formula provided in [Cameron, A., & Trivedi, P. (2005:43)](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/e240a/ch04iv.pdf).

$$\hat V[\hat \beta_{2SLS}] = N[X'P_ZX]^{-1}[X'Z(Z'Z)^{-1}\hat S(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'X][X'P_ZX]^{-1}$$

where

$$\hat S=N^{-1}\sum _i \hat u_i^2z_iz'_i$$

and

$$\hat u =y_i-x'_i\hat \beta_{2SLS}$$

Since you appear to using it, here is an implementation of a VCOV function in R code which can be used in `lmtest::coeftest`. For Stata users there is [another relevant answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126322/163114).

```
vcov2sls <- function(s1, s2) {
  X <- model.matrix(s2)
  dims <- dim(X)
  n <- dims[1]; p <- dims[2]
  mf <- model.frame(s1)
  y <- model.response(model.frame(s2))
  aux <- X  ## auxilliary model matrix
  aux[, 2L] <- as.numeric(model.response(mf))[seq_len(n)]
  b <- s2$coefficients
  r <- as.vector(y - aux %*% b)  ## residuals
  rss <- sum(r^2)
  rmse2 <- sqrt(mean(s2$residuals^2))  ## RMSE 2nd stage
  Rb <- vcov(s2)  ## biased vcov 2nd stage
  rmse <- sqrt(rss/n)
  corr <- (rmse/rmse2)^2
  R <- corr*Rb  ## corrected vcov
  return(R)
}
```

Here first the application with OLS models in both stages.

```
s1 <- lm(taxrate ~ votewon + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF)
yhat <- s1$fitted.values
s2 <- lm(sales ~ yhat + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF)

lmtest::coeftest(s2, vcov.=vcov2sls(s1, s2))
# t test of coefficients:
#   
#                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)   -18.45116   58.62518 -0.3147   0.7537
# yhat            1.57784    2.56770  0.6145   0.5405
# industryE       0.98174    4.81772  0.2038   0.8390
# industryF       2.09036    6.84134  0.3055   0.7607
# size2          -8.85327   11.73072 -0.7547   0.4524
# size3          -5.74011    6.74505 -0.8510   0.3970
# size4         -10.79326   12.40129 -0.8703   0.3865
# size5          -3.38280    5.14804 -0.6571   0.5128
# urbanisationB  -1.74588    5.98215 -0.2918   0.7711
# urbanisationC  -2.00370    6.11825 -0.3275   0.7441
# vote1          -1.01661    6.12665 -0.1659   0.8686
```

Identical with `AER::ivreg`:

```
fit1 <- AER::ivreg(sales ~ taxrate + industry + size + urbanisation + vote |
                     votewon + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF)
cbind(summary(fit1)$coe)
#                  Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)   -18.4511636  58.625184 -0.3147310 0.7537026
# taxrate         1.5778430   2.567702  0.6144961 0.5404553
# industryE       0.9817432   4.817719  0.2037776 0.8389925
# industryF       2.0903627   6.841342  0.3055486 0.7606618
# size2          -8.8532690  11.730721 -0.7547080 0.4524166
# size3          -5.7401121   6.745046 -0.8510115 0.3970468
# size4         -10.7932611  12.401290 -0.8703337 0.3864595
# size5          -3.3828028   5.148043 -0.6571047 0.5128093
# urbanisationB  -1.7458832   5.982153 -0.2918486 0.7710816
# urbanisationC  -2.0037006   6.118249 -0.3274958 0.7440620
# vote1          -1.0166078   6.126650 -0.1659321 0.8685868
```

Now we could calculate a tobit model in the first stage. (I use `AER::tobit` since `censReg` doesn't seem to provide the fitted values.)

```
s1.tobit <- AER::tobit(taxrate ~ votewon + industry + size + urbanisation + vote,
                       left=12, right=33, data=DF)
yhat <- fitted(s1.tobit)
s2.tobit <- lm(sales ~ yhat + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF)

lmtest::coeftest(s2.tobit, vcov.=vcov2sls(s1.tobit, s2.tobit))
# t test of coefficients:
#   
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)   -6.71785   35.49067 -0.1893   0.8503
# yhat           1.08249    1.57840  0.6858   0.4946
# industryE      0.40529    3.77675  0.1073   0.9148
# industryF      1.18311    5.03625  0.2349   0.8148
# size2         -7.28430    8.43989 -0.8631   0.3904
# size3         -5.38410    5.78586 -0.9306   0.3546
# size4         -9.17192    9.06884 -1.0114   0.3146
# size5         -3.95675    4.27762 -0.9250   0.3575
# urbanisationB -2.50969    4.57805 -0.5482   0.5849
# urbanisationC -2.66487    4.80591 -0.5545   0.5806
# vote1         -0.60525    4.97518 -0.1217   0.9034
```

There might be objections to using a Tobit model in the first stage, but I am not aware of any.

---

***Data:***

```
DF <- structure(list(country = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "J", "J", "B", 
"B", "F", "F", "E", "E", "D", "D", "F", "F", "I", "I", "J", "J", 
"E", "E", "C", "C", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "C", "C", "H", 
"H", "J", "J", "G", "G", "J", "J", "I", "I", "C", "C", "D", "D", 
"A", "A", "G", "G", "E", "E", "J", "J", "G", "G", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "J", "J", "G", "G", "E", "E", "G", "G", "E", "E", "F", "F", 
"I", "I", "B", "B", "E", "E", "H", "H", "B", "B", "A", "A", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "F", "F", "E", "E", "I", "I", "J", "J", "D", "D", 
"F", "F"), year = c(2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 
2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 
2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 
2005, 2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2005, 
2010, 2010, 2005, 2010, 2005), sales = c(15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9, 15.48, 12.39, 3.72, 
23.61, 4, 31.87, 25.33, 7.64, -0.26, 2.9), industry = c("D", 
"D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", 
"E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D", "F", "F", "E", "E", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "F", 
"F", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", 
"E", "F", "F", "E", "E", "F", "F", "E", "E", "F", "F", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "F", "F"), urbanisation = c("B", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), size = c(1, 1, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5), base_rate = c(14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 29L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 29L, 29L, 14L, 14L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 33L, 33L, 19L, 19L, 24L, 
24L, 14L, 14L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 23L, 33L, 33L, 29L, 29L, 19L, 19L, 
33L, 33L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 33L, 33L, 29L, 29L, 33L, 
33L, 29L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 29L, 17L, 17L, 
30L, 30L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 29L, 29L, 24L, 
24L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), taxrate = c(12L, 14L, 14L, 
12L, 21L, 18L, 30L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 29L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
24L, 24L, 21L, 18L, 30L, 29L, 14L, 12L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 14L, 12L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 21L, 33L, 32L, 21L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 
12L, 14L, 20L, 20L, 22L, 25L, 32L, 33L, 30L, 29L, 18L, 21L, 32L, 
33L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 18L, 21L, 32L, 33L, 30L, 29L, 32L, 33L, 
29L, 30L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 18L, 19L, 30L, 
30L, 22L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 29L, 24L, 24L, 
21L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), vote = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), votewon = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))

## convert variables to factors beforehand
DF[c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10)] <- lapply(DF[c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10)], factor)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is absolutely amazing. If there are any objections to the first stage being a tobit model I guess I can always report the normal and tobit-2SLS alongside each other. Once again, thank you very much, I am very grateful for it!

Comment: Hi jay.sf. I have a small question which is a bit of a long shot.. I was running your code on my actual data, and I noticed that the line `DATA <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(phantom ~ ., transform(data, phantom=0)))` from `vcov2sls`, gives me the `Error in contrasts<-(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels` error. Do you, from the top of your head have any idea why it might show up there, while `s1.tobit` and `s2.tobit` do not have that problem?

Comment: @TomKisters Your issue seems to be caused by factor variables that have no variance. I could replicate the problem by doing `DF$vote <- factor(1)` befor running the regressions or your cited line. It might also be possible that they're all `NA`, i.e. `DF$vote <- factor(NA)`. Hope that helps. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Jay, I was revisiting your question and I noticed that you use the predicted values `yhat <- predict(s1.tobit)` instead of the fitted values, when estimating `s2.tobit <- lm(sales ~ yhat + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF)` . Could you perhaps explain to me why that is? Are they not different for a tobit, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201439/is-there-a-difference-between-the-r-functions-fitted-and-predict?

Comment: I just check and apparently it does not matter for the result. Weirdly enough, on my actual data, I could not get the predicted or fitted values to stick to the restrictions. Not when doing `predict(s1.tobit, type="response")`or `fitted(s1.tobit)`.  I had to resort to a glm logit. Do you have any idea what the cause of that could be?

Comment: @TomKisters No, you're right, `fitted()` is better, because we actually refer to $\hat Y$ – thanks, edited. However, `predict()` and `predict(..., type="response")` should be synonymous because the former calls the `AER:::fitted.tobit` method which code is `function(object, ...) predict(object, type="response", se.fit=FALSE)`.

Comment: Okay thank you. For some reason neither of those options gives me predictions within the censored limit. I will maybe post it on stackoverflow tomorrow if I can reproduce it.

Comment: @TomKisters Now I got what you implied. Why do you expect predictions to be in the censored limit? Actually we have censored data and intend to fit a model that takes account of the censoring, i.e. a tobit. But why do you think that the predictions should also be censored? Actually, that should be precisely what we don't want, do we?

Comment: Well, I actually was not sure and considered what you are arguing. I posted a question about that as well (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502538/predicted-values-well-outside-of-the-censored-range). Then I found this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11985/how-to-model-bounded-target-variable, which convinced me of the need of also censoring the predictions. I completely see the rational of your argument though. There isn't any chance of you having journal article or book chapter reference for this right? Wanted to say that Im very grateful for your help by the way:)

Comment: @TomKisters I'm delighted:) Unfortunately I don't know a source. However, you could try to censor the predictions using `survival::Surv(time=ifelse(yhat >= 33, 33, ifelse(yhat <= 12, 12, yhat)), time2=33, event=ifelse(yhat >= 33, 0, ifelse(yhat <= 12, 2, 1)), type="interval")`, I'm not sure how to make `vcov2sls` work then, though. `AER::ivreg` can be considered as a convenience function, because `S.taxrate <- with(DF, survival::Surv(time=ifelse(taxrate >= 33, 33, ifelse(taxrate <= 12, 12, taxrate)), time2=33, event=ifelse(taxrate >= 33, 0, ifelse(taxrate <= 12, 2, 1)), type="interval"));` ...

Comment: @TomKisters ... `survival::survreg(S.taxrate ~ votewon + industry + size + urbanisation + vote, data=DF, dist="gaussian")` gives an identical result. May this help!

Comment: I am going try it out!. Can I also use your function to `vcov2sls` to correct the standard error if the first stage is `lm` and the second stage is `tobit` by the way? If I cannot, I will post a new question about it. Most of the work is done: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66856/instrumental-variable-tobit-in-r but I am having some trouble with the implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595081/correcting-the-standard-errors-when-the-second-stage-is-a-tobit-regression

Comment: @TomKisters I don't see why we may not then use `vcov2sls` as well, since we are practically just correcting for the fact that yhat is an estimate.

Comment: Okay, so that would make the question you just answered and just using `vcov2sls` identical, right? (Because for some reason the bootstrap method keeps giving me another estimate, I am trying to figure the cause but I cannot find it) because of which I cannot be sure about the result.. Just using  `vcov2sls`  might be better then?

Comment: Darn it, there is no `vcov` in `AER::tobit`, `censReg` or `survival::Surv`/`survival::survreg` it seems..

Comment: @TomKisters In principle `vcov2sls` should be the analytical approach to what we've bootstrapped [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595081/correcting-the-standard-errors-when-the-second-stage-is-a-tobit-regression).

Comment: Hi jay.sf, I got a little stuck with your function haha, if you would be willing to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65651392/model-matrix-turning-factors-into-dummies

Comment: @TomKisters Code should be fixed for interactions now. We also got rid of the "phantom" :) Could test this thoroughly?

Comment: Thank you so much, yes I'm on it immediately.

Comment: I believe `DATA` should be `data`. Apart from that I tried two different interaction (with the data above), always giving me only coefficients, se, t, and p are all NA.

Comment: I added a random variable to the data.frame and the interacted that random variable. In that case is works.

Comment: 2sls works only if your first stage is linear. Tobit is not linear, and your model looks a lot like a forbidden regression (https://benjamindwilliams.weebly.com/uploads/6/8/5/7/68575765/notesonforbiddenregressions.pdf, or Mostly Harmless Econometrics)

Comment: Hi Otto. According to your posted blog, it will still be consistent when the first stage is properly specified (but just not a 2SLS), correct?

Comment: Also an ILS seems to be a good way out as it might even be more efficient according to the blog.

Comment: Sorry, the Ben Williams notes are not as clear as I rememberesd. I would still suggest proceeding with cautio. Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94063/probit-two-stage-least-squares-2sls/94392#94392 (this is about proving but results generalize to all nonlinear models)

Comment: Thanks Otto! That post is really helpful!